# how to make an animation using css transform property on repeat

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I started [this](https://codepen.io/jreecebowman/pen/gdemLB?editors=1100http://) pen quite mindlessly, and ended up making a kind of animation using the css transform property:

HTML

```
<div class="logo-block">
  <div class="logo-block-yellow"></div>
  <div class="logo-block-magenta"></div>
  <div class="logo-block-cyan"></div>
  <div class="logo-block-black"></div>
</div>
```

CSS (SCSS)

```
.logo-block {
  height: 332px;
  width: 332px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  .logo-block-yellow {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 8px;
  }
  .logo-block-magenta {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    background-color: magenta;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 8px;
  }
  .logo-block-cyan {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    background-color: cyan;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 8px;
  }
  .logo-block-black {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    background-color: black;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 8px;
  }
  &:hover {
    .logo-block-yellow {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform-origin: 105% 105%;
      transition: transform 1s;
    }
    .logo-block-magenta {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform-origin: -5% 105%;
      transition: transform 1s;
    }
    .logo-block-cyan {
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      transform-origin: -5% -5%;
      transition: transform 1s;
    }
    .logo-block-black {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform-origin: -5% -5%;
      transition: transform 1s;
    }
  }
}
```

What I can't work out though, is how to get the process to repeat, so that the blocks move round in the same way until all the colours are back where they started.

I don't have any experience using css animations, and my use of JavaScript is pretty basic (I only started learning quite recently).

I've seen the animate-iteration property which works for animations, but as this isn't an animation, I guess I can't use it? Is it worth trying to convert my transform properties into equivalent animation properties?

Any suggestions are greatly welcome, whether they are beyond my level of understanding or not!

Thanks

Jamie

PS Sorry it's quite a mess - not really sure what I'm up to here.

Comment: you mean you want the animation when mouse leaves? your transition is on :hover, so when your mouse leaves there's no transition on the elements

Comment: sorry, it's a bit misleading because of the :hover. i actually just want the animation to continue on it's own (like a spinner when a page is loading). thanks

Comment: then you need animation instead of transition